# Error message for non-existent folder when trying to create new page in XPM

Tags: experience-manager, web8.5

SDL Web 8.5

1. I go to an existing page.
2. I select "new page" from ribbon
3. I click "create a new page" from page types
4. I provide title, file name
5. I click  "configure folders for Components"

Result:

[[image: Error Message in XPM interface[1]]

The TCM id is for an item that no longer exists. I have tried to setup Content Types via the "Content Types" tab in the publication.

1. I created a content type
2. Added a description, content title
3. pointed to a "prototype component" and schema
4. created a storage location and component template

Result:
Same as above.

How can I get XPM to use a different default folder for creating components?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It might be one the components on the page type that is causing the issue. Are there any predefined components defined on your page type?

If you open up the page type in CME and check the component presentations. Each component presentation has its own page type settings. Here you can define a folder for components that you clone (each time you create a new instance of this page type). My guess is that one of those folders are faulty.

A page type is basically just a standard page with the option "Use as a page type" checked.